# Integrating postman collection tests in travis

Tags: python, postman, travis-ci

I have a travis integration in my project with build language as python. I want to integrate postman test which requires Node installation. Should i create a separate build for this? Is there a way to accommodate this in the same build. I tried adding a new env but apparently I was getting the tox error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad guideline. Ideally:

1. The jobs are atomic (independent of setup and run)
2. You install npm or configure Travis to have npm setup alongside Python
3. You run your jobs in the order you desire (usually [Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/continuous-integration/) last)

It seems nowdays you can have a language per job in Travis. Check: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/#using-different-programming-languages-per-job. For example:

```
dist: xenial
language: php
php:
  - '5.6'

jobs:
  include:
    - language: python
      python: 3.8
      script:
      - python -c "print('Hi from Python!')"

    - language: node_js
      node_js: 12
      script:
      - npm i newman -g
      - newman run COLLECTION
```

So this will likely allow you to keep one single build + test run.